# How to prevent this kind of bug - pattern matching and Nil

Tags: scala

When you pattern match again Lists, you can use Nil to check for empty list. However, if the underlying type is an Iterable, you can still check for Nil, and it will break for empty Sets, etc... See following REPL session:

```
scala> val l: Iterable[Int] = List()
l: Iterable[Int] = List()

scala> l match {
     | case Nil => 1
     | case _ => 2
     | }
res0: Int = 1

scala> val l: Iterable[Int] = Set() 
l: Iterable[Int] = Set()

scala> l match {
     | case Nil => 1
     | case _ => 2
     | }
res2: Int = 2
```

Question is - how can I prevent this kind of issue? Obviously, if l is a type List, it's no bug. And if l is of type Set, it won't compile. But what if we have a class that has a list, define a function that pattern matches in this way, and then someone changes the class to take a generic iterable instead? Is this Nil vs. _ pattern match a bad idea in general?

Comment: Subtyping is a double-edged sword; use with care.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the scrutinee to a list to eliminate doubt.

```
l.toList match {
  case Nil => 1
  case xs  => 2
}
```

Comment: Yep. `.toSeq` is also sufficent. `(Vector(): Seq[Int]) match { case Nil => 0 }`.

Comment: But this relies solely on the fact that `Nil.equals` is overriden so that `Nil` is equal to any empty seq. This is undocumented, so I would not rely on it (so better use `toList` over `toSeq` as in your answer, it involves less magic).

Answer (score 12):

One possibility is to use a guard:

```
scala> val xs: Iterable[Int] = Set()
xs: Iterable[Int] = Set()

scala> xs match { case xs if xs.isEmpty => 1 case _ => 2 }
res0: Int = 1
```

Another way to do this is to use an if-else-expression (works best if you only have one or two conditions to check):

```
scala> if (xs.isEmpty) 1 else 2
res1: Int = 1
```

Comment: The if else is how I ended up doing it. Just seems not as idiomatic.

Comment: Imho the best way for pattern matching collections

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option (pun intended):

```
scala> val l: Iterable[Int] = List()
l: Iterable[Int] = List()

scala> l.headOption match { case None => 1; case Some(h) => 2 }
res0: Int = 1
```

This is useful in cases where you pattern match in order to get the `head` like in popular `List() match { case h :: t => ... }` but it's not a list, it's an `Iterable` and **`::` will fail**.

I added this answer because I thought it's quite common to pattern match on a collection to get a head, otherwise you can just check with `xs.isEmpty`.